# How to send data to a socket server?

Tags: android, vb.net, sockets

I have a code in VB.NET to create a socket server. I need to create an application for Android that send data to it and it shows the received message on the screen.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text

Public Module Module1
    Private IPAddress As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.100")
    Private IPEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress, 11000)
    Private Socket As Socket = Nothing

    Public Sub Main()
        Try
            Socket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
            If Not IsNothing(Socket) Then
                Socket.Bind(IPEndPoint)
                Socket.Listen(10)

                While (True)
                    Dim handler As Socket = Socket.Accept()
                    Dim data As String = ""

                    While (True)
                        Dim bytes(handler.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
                        Dim bytesRec As Integer = handler.Receive(bytes)
                        data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec)
                        If data.Length > 0 Then
                            Exit While
                        End If
                    End While

                    Console.WriteLine("Mensagem recebida: " & data & "")

                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)
                    handler.Close()
                End While
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

The above code is a code in VB.NET that opens the socket server to receive messages from clients. The problem is that I need to create a client with Android code.

I've tried to create a client, check the code below.

```
package com.pcriot.maxsoft.testapp;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView LabelStatus = null;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LabelStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LabelStatus);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.0.100", 11000);

                    DataInputStream DIStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    DataOutputStream DOStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                    String msg = "teste";
                    DOStream.write(msg.getBytes(), 0, msg.getBytes().length);
                    DOStream.flush();

                    String text = DIStream.readLine();
                    LabelStatus.setText(text);

                    DOStream.close();
                    DIStream.close();

                    socket.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LabelStatus.setText(e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

I found no error, the client and the server appears to be correct. But when I open the server on my computer and access the app on my smartphone, no message is received. What is the error?

Ps: I set INTERNET permission on AndroidManifest.

Comment: Do you debug your app ? where you are failing in your code ?

Comment: I don't know where the error is, and I don't use virtual android to debug because the virtual android is slow. Any error should appear in LabelStatus but it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Hi added a link which provide a nice tutorial for socket server programming for android where you can find sending and receiving code [please click here to see the code](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/)